# Dimension of center of $k[G]/\mathrm{rad}k[G]$ when characteristic of $k$ divides the order of $G$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups, noncommutative-algebra, group-rings

Let $G$ be a finite group and consider $k[G]$ where $k$ is a field. In the scenario where $\mathrm{char}(k)$ divides $|G|$, how can one show that the dimension of $Z(k[G]/\operatorname{rad}k[G])$ is **strictly less** than dimension of $Z(k[G])$?

I'm trying to use this to show that in the case where char(*k*) divides $|G|$, the number of simple modules (up to isomorphism) is strictly less than no. of conjugacy classes of $G$. I'm aware of the fact that this can be answered using some knowledge of characters but I'm wondering if the above line of attack is also possible?

Remark: In the case where $\operatorname{char}(k)$ does not divide $|G|$, we have that $\operatorname{rad}(k[G])$ is trivial since $k[G]$ is semisimple and therefore $Z(k[G]/\operatorname{rad}k[G]) = Z(k[G])$ and it can be shown that the number of simple modules is **at most** the number of conjugacy classes by considering dimension of $Z(k[G])$.

Thank you in advance for any light that can be shed on the matter! :)

Comment: If $k$ is not a splitting field the dimension of $Z(kG/Rad(kG))$ is not the number of simple modules. If it is a splitting field then the number of $p$-regular classes gives the number of simples.

Comment: The corresponding post on [math.se]: [Dimension of center of k\[G\]/rad k\[G\] where characteristic of k divides the order of G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3632646). When [meta-tag:cross-posting], it is [recommended to link each of the copies to the other ones](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638).